# Can't get AUC higher than 0.62 using XGBoost or Random forest

Tags: machine-learning, python, roc

I have a dataframe with multiple numeric predictive features, and one binary target feature. 63% of the data belongs to class `0`, and the rest to class `1`. So the data is imbalanced but not severely.

I aim to build a classifier, using Random forests or xgboost.

I'm using cross validation with `GridSearchCV`, I tired with and without feature selection (in both algorithms), I tuned the hyperparameters as much as I could, I tried many different numbers for each parameter, like `max_depth`, `min_samples_leaf` and more.. using the `grid_params` argument.

I'm using `roc_auc_score` to evaluate the models, and the best outcome so far was AUC = 0.61 in both algorithms. What could be the reason for such poor results in your opinion?

##### EDIT:

I tried also Kernel SVM and logistic regression. They failed, with AUC = 0.6 and 0.55. Random forest and gradient boosting machines (and xgboost) were the best among those, altough they still produce poor results. Still can't figure out what improvements can I make.

Comment: what's the gap between tree-based methods and weaker learners like logistic reg?

Comment: A logistic regression model produces AUC = 0.53, much worse.

Comment: Why *should* you achieve higher performance than that?

Comment: @Dave Just trying to improve it, the higher the better. I found my self at a dead end, which is why I'm here trying to find some answers.